MAX9814 output desired for full swing 0 - 3.3V but data sheet says only 0.003 - 2.45V
I am using a MAX9814 mic pre amplifier to make an interphone with an ESP32. The data sheet says I can run it off Vdd = 3.3V or higher up to 5.5V. And I have 5V on my board. The ADC input pin of the ESP32 wants 0 to 3.3V. But when I choose Vdd = 3.3V for the MAX9814, the data sheet says that its output goes between 3 mV and 2.45 V. So that means I want to use my 5 V power supply and then adjust the output voltage to be 3.3 V max, perhaps with a simple two resistor voltage divider.
But I don't see in the datasheet what the output voltage is if I run it at 5V? If I apply the same proportion I get 3.72 V, but perhaps it's not the same proportion if the drop of 0.85V is due to a fixed 0.7 V PN forward voltage drop + a variable part of 0.15 V, in that case that would be 0.23 for a combined loss of 0.93 V, i.e., the output would be between 3 mV and 4.7 V.
I suppose I could put a potentiometer component to my voltage divider so I can adjust for 3.72 V to 4.7 V to 3.3 V conversion.
But is there any way to do it more precisely? Or maybe to simply adjust the gain or any of the resistors on the other pins.
Also, doesn't it matter which microphone is used? The elecrtret microphone that I have actually comes in with almost 3.3 V when you shout into it, so it's just about a gain of 1 that's required.
I wonder if I should go for making the PCB computing everything before even building it on a breadboard first?

Are you aware that it also specifies a maximum output voltage of 0.707 VRMS? The THD+N goes up drastically above that point, as shown in the bottom-center graph on page 4. It's possible that will be different at 5 V supply, but this chip doesn't have much information on 5 V operation at all.

Whats wrong with using the 3mV-2.45V range? Just because the ADC can accept up to 3.3V doesn't mean you have to use that whole range of values.

The datasheet of the MAX9814 says the maximum output level is 0.707 RMS of VCC. It also says it might be 1% of that value. (which is the inverse of the square root of 2, with a bit of rounding)
For an VCC of 3.3V, you are getting 2.3331V RMS / 3.3VPP out.
For an VCC of 5V, you are getting 3.535V RMS / 5VPP out.
Since you want to covert this signal to a 3.3VPP signal for your ADC, you can use resistors:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Also this circuit in the fallstad simulator
If you cannot load the 3.3V rail that much, you can also use a resistor to 5v:


So if this means 3.3 Vpp output, coming from the output pin, that means I keep it at Vdd = 3.3V and can connect it directly, no coupling capacitor and re-biasing needed, no?
